# Some questons about recurrence sequences (using a problem).

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

A quick doubt, lets study the recurrence sequence:

$A_{n+1}=(4A_n +2)/A_n+3$;

$A_{0}<-3$

First of all i do:

$A_{n+1}-A_{n}<0$

If this is true i can say that $A_n$ decrease.
This is true for those $A_n$ values:

$-3>A_n>-1$

$A_n>2$

And false (so $A_n$ increase) for those $A_n$ values:

$A_n<-3$

$-1<A_n<2$

the case $A_n<-3$ interests me.

The limit $L$ can be $-1$ or $-2$ but i cannot say it exists for sure because $A_n$ is not limited and monotone for all the $A_n$ possible values. For example, the sequence can go from $A_n>2$ then decrease and go in $A_n<-3$ then again increase and fall in $A_n>2$ etc...

Another doubt comes from this fact:

It's ok to remove $-1$ from the possible values of $L$ because in this case the sequence still growing?

Anyways:
It happens so many times that i know the sequence increase or decrease in an interval but i don't know if doing it it will fall in another interval where it starts decreasing or increasing and in this scenario i don't know how to demonstrate if it goes on some limit or just starts to "ping-pong" on different intervals.

Or in other words i don't know how many it decrease/increase so i cannot say if it will go out from the interval i'm considering.

Hopefully i was clear.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean $A_{n+1}=(4A_n+2)/(A_n+3)$? Else the specific exclusion of $-3$ in $A_0<-3$ does not make much sense.

Comment: I just took it from an analysis excercise book :|

Comment: Then in all probability there was a communication problem somewhere in the chain from the brain of the textbook author to the formula in the question. The corrected formula is too nice and the formula as is leads to too ugly numbers for an exercise book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume for the moment that the recursive sequence converges. Then the limit would satisfy the quadratic equation 
$$
L(L+3)=4L+2\iff 0=L^2-L-2=(L-2)(L+1)
$$
Take the negative fixed point $L=-1$ and consider the sequence $B_n=A_n+1$ or $A_n=-1+B_n$. Then
$$
B_{n+1}=1+\frac{-4+4B_n+2}{-1+B_n+3}=\frac{5B_n}{B_n+2}
$$
which tells that the iteration will move away from that fixed point with speed around $\frac52$ except in the case where $B_0=0$, $A_0=-1$, which is excluded.

For the second fixed point $L=2$ a similar consideration with $A_n=2+C_n$ gives
$$
C_{n+1}=-2+\frac{4(2+C_n)+2}{C_n+2+3}=\frac{2C_n}{C_n+5}
$$

Now if $A_0<-3$, then $C_0<-5$ and $C_1>0$ so that $0<C_{n+1}<\dfrac25C_n$ for $n>1$. Thus the sequence $(C_n)_n$ converges to $0$, in consequence $(A_n)_n$ to $2$.

Comment: Sounds legit. Those recurrence sequences are hard peanuts!  Thanks for all!

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect oscillating behavior, then apply the recursion twice, i.e., examine how $A_{n+2}$ depends on $A_n$.

In the case of fractions of linear terms one can fully linearize the problem by writing $A_n=P_n/Q_n$, $P_0=A_0$, $Q_0=1$ and using the one degree of freedom to extract from
$$
\frac{P_{n+1}}{Q_{n+1}}=A_{n+1}=\frac{4A_n+2}{A_n+3}=\frac{4P_n+2Q_n}{P_n+3Q_n}
$$
the linear system
$$
\begin{bmatrix}P_{n+1}\\Q_{n+1}\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}4&2\\1&3\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}P_{n}\\Q_{n}\end{bmatrix}
$$
As the characteristic equation is 
$$
0=z^2-7z+10=(z-2)(z-5)
$$
the roots are $z_1=5$ and $z_2=2$ with eigenvectors $v_1=\binom{2}{1}$ and $v_2=\binom{1}{-1}$.

The solution will thus have the form $P_n=2c_15^n+c_22^n$, $Q_n=c_15^n-c_22^n$, $Q_0=1\implies c_2=c_1-1$, $P_0=A_0\implies c_1=\frac13(A_0+1)$ and thus
$$
A_n=\frac{2(A_0+1)5^n+(A_0-2)2^n}{(A_0+1)5^n-(A_0-2)2^n}
=\frac{2(A_0+1)+(A_0-2)(\frac25)^n}{(A_0+1)-(A_0-2)(\frac25)^n}
$$
Which will in all but one exceptional case (where $c_1=0$, i.e., $A_0=-1$) converge to $2$.

Comment: Well, that's  sightly above the knowledge expected to solve those problems...   ...my analysis book asks to solve those problems just after he explained some basics things about induction and functions. (the solution still right)

Comment: OK, I'll put another answer with some more elementary ideas.